# Creating github license and choosing which branch to commit to

Tags: git, github

I created license for my github project and Github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/setting-up-your-project-for-healthy-contributions/adding-a-license-to-a-repository) said:

> Below the commit message fields, decide whether to add your commit to the current branch or to a new branch. **If your current branch is the default branch, you should choose to create a new branch for your commit and then create a pull request**. For more information, see "Creating a new pull request."

The **bold** text confuses me. My current branch is `main` and I think it is default branch, so why should I create pull request, **why can't I choose the "commit to main" option**? (there are two options: commit on main and create pull request). Screenshot also creates a pull request:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ADB.png)

So given I was on main branch to begin with, can't I choose the **commit to main** option above on the screenshot? (first option)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can just commit it to the default (main in this case) branch without issues.

The docs just want to guide you into following best practice for collaboration and use the Pull Request mechanisme. It’s valid to notify people to use it, but if you are working by yourself, it can definitely be skipped.